# Rails action inheritance and nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using nested resources in my Rails app like so:

```
resources :devices, :except => [:edit] do
    resources :services, :only => [:index, :destroy], :controller => "devices/services"
    resources :alerts,   :only => [:index, :destroy], :controller => "devices/alerts"
end
```

Now what I want to do is have the devices/show view be the "layout" for the nested resources and
any other sub-actions that I define.

So say my devices/show.html.erb looks like this:

```
<div class="resource">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <ul>
      <li><%= active_link_to "General", @device, :active => :exclusive %></li>
      <li><%= active_link_to "Services", device_services_path(@device) %></li>
      <li><%= active_link_to "Alerts", device_alerts_path(@device) %></li>
      etc..
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="data">
    <%= render "shared/flash_messages" %>
    <%= yield %>
  </div>
</div>
```

So how do I go about rendering the sub-view (devices/services/index.html.erb, devices/alerts/index.html.erb) where the (hypothetical) yield is in the #data div?

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: yield only works on layouts AFAIK. I tried this and the yield doesn't render anything...

Comment: So your question is about how to use yield? In which case you should look at using content_for http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-content_for

Comment: Yup. I totally forgot about that. I used that and nested layouts to solve this. Thanks!!

Comment: lol :) Glad you got it sorted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your question is absolutely nothing to do with inheritance and nested resources.

If you want to know how to use the yield command I posted a link in my comment to your question but here is an example specifically for your code

```
<div class="resource">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <ul>
      <li><%= active_link_to "General", @device, :active => :exclusive %></li>
      <li><%= active_link_to "Services", device_services_path(@device) %></li>
      <li><%= active_link_to "Alerts", device_alerts_path(@device) %></li>
      etc..
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="data">
    <%= render "shared/flash_messages" %>
    <%= yield :nested_resources %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then wherever you want to place anything in that div wrap it up in a content_for :nested_resources block e.g.
In a view template somewhere

```
<% content_for :nested_resources do %>
  <!-- whatever code you would normally have in your view template -->
<% end %>
```